# Problems with defining a new environment using comments

Tags: beamer, comments

In some of my frames, I want to state a source, where I've found the information for this frame. But this kind of source should be invisible.

So, I tried to define my own environment and putting its content in comments. But, it doesn't want to work. :/

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{comment}

\newenvironment {source}[1]
{\begin{comment}#1}
{\end{comment}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \source{Page 123} % should be invisible
        My MWE
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define it as `\newenvironment{source}{intro stuff}{outro stuff}`, then you use it as

```
\begin{source}
content
\end{source}
```

If you define it as `\newenvironment{source}[1]{intro stuff}{outro stuff}`, then you use it as

```
\begin{source}{This is item 1}
content
\end{source}
```

If you define it as `\newcommand{\source}[1]{command definition}`, then you use it as `\source{This is item 1}`.

But if you're already including the comment package, and just want to throw the contents away, you can just say `\excludecoment{source}`.  This is equivalent to your definition, so that you can use it as

```
\begin{source}
content
\end{source}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `\source`, so it shouldn't be defined with `\newenvironment`.

For a “disappearing” command, the trick should be

```latex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother
```

that basically tell LaTeX to ignore the argument to `\source`, as well as the space following it.